# Angular mat-form-field encapsulated in child component

Tags: angular, angular-forms

is there an easy to follow example which shows how to encapsulate a `mat-form-field` in a child component?

What I want

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <my-component 
      formControlName="someFormValue"
      label="hi">
  </my-component>
<form>
```

and in my-component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>
    {{ label }}
  </mat-label>
  <input
    matInput
    ...
  />
  <mat-error>
    .... some form validation errors here
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

the best bet is pass as `@Input` the FormControl -not the formControlName-

```
  <my-component 
      [control]="form.get('someFormField')"
      label="hi">
  </my-component>
```

and use in the component

```
@Input()control:FormControl

//in .html

<mat-form-field>
  ...
  <!--see that you use [formControl] directly-->
  <input matInput [formControl]="control"/>
  <mat-error>
    .... some form validation errors here...
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Updated**: a [quick stackblitz](http://I%20make%20a%20%22quick%20stackblitz%22:%20https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b2w9fg?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.html)

Comment: Thxs, that is a good solution to my problem. And it makes it even easier to work with nested forms `form.get('nested.value')` :)

Comment: However, now Ii see this error: 

`ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute`

Comment: add the attribute `name='myinput'`

Comment: I had do implement the ControlValueAccessor interface to get rid of this error message :(

Comment: I make a "quick stackblitz": https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b2w9fg?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.html

Comment: @abnormi In order to get rid of this message, remove the original formControlName-attribute of the parent control, since now [control] will do the assignment now instead. ControlValueAccessor is not needed.